# IntelliJ - How to find all method names matching a string pattern?

Tags: intellij-idea

Trying to find any method name in my project matching a specific sub-string.

The example I'm currently looking for is "domain", so I'd want to see `getDomain()`, `setDomain()`,  `domainThing()`, etc. in the results.  Looking for static/instance methods of any visibility.

`Find Symbol` (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+N) comes close, but there's too many classes and fields cluttering up the results.  Is there a way to restrict `Find Symbol` to only methods?  Or at least group the results by symbol type?

`Structural Search` might be the answer, but it's comically unusable interface and documentation have defeated me once again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SSR](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html) is the way to go. There is an [existing template for the methods of the class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGbjB.png) you can start with.

Click on `$Method$`, Edit filters, [Add filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9daR.png), Text.

Enter regex to match your methods, for example `.*domain.*`.

Uncheck the Match case checkbox.

The final result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: That got it, thanks.  Even with explicit instructions, I still stuffed it up a few times.